# Where can I find a list of investigational drugs?

Tags: data-request, drugs, medical

I am looking for a primary source (read: preferably not from a reseller) of all drugs currently in development. The FDA says they don't disclose the information, and it seems that clinicaltrials.gov has the information, but there's no easy way to pull out the names of all the drugs in ct.gov.

Are there any other authoritative sources for investigational drugs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

drugbank.ca -which has listed over 11000 drugs- offers the possibility to filter for investigational drugs. see https://www.drugbank.ca/categories?utf8=%E2%9C%93&investigational=1&us=0&canada=0&eu=0&commit=Apply+Filter

Answer (score 1):

There are a couple of reference sources for drugs, like WHO-DD (world health Organisation-drug dictionary), or INNs (international non-proprietary names) but to my knowledge these do not contain an explicit listing of drugs currently under test.

Checking [clinical trials dot gov](http://www.who.int/medicines/services/inn/en/) shows there's also a database version of that data called [AACT](https://aact-prod.herokuapp.com). It should be possible to access the active substances separately there.

Comment: AACT helped. But what about finding the name of the company that owns the drug?